# Cleaning up after installing library

Tags: linux, software-installation

As part of installing ImageMagick and PDFtk I fetched tarballs and extracted them to my home directory. I went through installation process and got both libraries working.

If I run `which` on pdftk or any ImageMagick command I get `/usr/local/bin`/ as the location.

I know I can `rm` the tarballs, but can I also remove the extracted folders `/home/myuser/ImageMagick-6.9.1-3/`  and `/home/myuser/pdftk-2.02-dist/`?  It's my impression that those are no longer needed after `make install`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, you don't need to keep the extracted source code. If you want to be sure of it before deleting the folders, you can rename them and check that ImageMagick and PDFtk still work...

It may be useful to keep the original archives you downloaded along with a note of the commands you used to configure the builds. If you ever want to uninstall the programs, you'll be able to extract the archives, run `configure` and then uninstall using `make uninstall` (if that's supported).